# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jzlib/ZStream With Spring Boot Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, sftp

```java
JSch jsch = new JSch();  
session = jsch.getSession(variable1,variable2); 
session.setPassword(abcd);  
session.setConfig(config);  
session.connect();  
channel = session.openChannel("sftp");  
channel.connect();
```

I'm using this code with this POM dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.55</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm facing this error in the runtime environment:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jzlib/ZStream

Comment: Why are you using `<scope>provided</scope>`? Do you know what this means?

Comment: For Provided Scope in both runtime and compile scope dependencies will be pulled in with the provided scope in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

when I saw the source code of downloaded Jar in the Library didn't reach out this `com/jcraft/jzlib/ZStream` path then i'll find out another Maven Dependency of jcraft

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jzlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

and they have the same classes which are missing in base dependency. Now its work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The scope `provided` means, that the library will not be packed into your application. Remove the scope:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.55</version>
</dependency>
```

or put the jar into your runtime environment

Comment: Already Use with out or with Scope still same issue

Comment: do you build a jar or a war?

Comment: building the Jar